# Umbraco VS Craft CMS

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco, craftcms

I cannot find any good comparisons between Umbraco and Craft CMS.  What are the strengths/weaknesses between the two?

I am a sole developer (owner) for a marketing agency and have projects/sites of varying sizes and types. My major considerations are how time consuming it is to develop basic sites, how much maintenance time goes into things like updating, what the platform isn't capable of / where I will run into problems for larger projects, how well it handles things like SEO and page speed etc, and of course all in long term costs.

Comment: First of all, this isn't a StackOverlow kind of question, as it doesn't have a finite answer/solution. Second, without knowing what you need to be able to do it's pretty difficult to tell you what you need. Third, I'm super biased in that I know nothing about Craft CMS but I still want to tell you that Umbraco is very flexible and has zero "restrictions" regarding your fromtend website. There are litteraly no restrictions as long as you can fit the content into the (also very flexible) backend structure Umbraco offers OOTB.

Comment: Like @jannikAnker never heard of Craft and Umbraco is literally world wide and over 25 years old, that alone tells you all you need to decide. Basically from my experience with umbraco you can make it as simple or as complex as you want.

Answer (score 1):

It ultimately comes down to what platform you're most comfortable working with.

I'm a big fan of Umbraco, and I've used it for the better part of a decade on both small brochureware sites and huge builds. It's probably the best CMS available on the .NET platform, and it's easy to get something built quickly with minimal fuss.

I've also used Craft in the past, and I think it's a great CMS, albeit not as user friendly as Umbraco, but as long as you're providing adequate user training it shouldn't matter.

Umbraco's weakness isn't really a weakness, it's a preference. Being a .NET CMS, you are limited to the .NET platform on Windows, and many developers would prefer to not develop on Windows tooling. If building and hosting on Windows is a problem for you, choose Craft, otherwise I'd recommend Umbraco.